# remove next all including ($this) using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Here's a quickie:

Is there a better jquery alternative to remove next all, including ($this)?

So far, this works for me: `$(this).nextAll().remove();$(this).remove();`

Comment: if by better alternative you mean obnoxious chaining then `$(this).nextAll().remove().end().remove();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to chain your calls then there are a few options however it doesn't change much in the way of performance:

```
$(this).nextAll().remove().end().remove();

$(this).nextAll().add(this).remove();

$(this).nextAll().andSelf().remove();
```

`.end()`:

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and
>   return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

http://api.jquery.com/end

`.add()`:

> Add elements to the set of matched elements.

http://api.jquery.com/add

`.andSelf()`:

> Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set.

http://api.jquery.com/andself

Comment: `$(this).nextAll().add(this).remove();` is cleaner.

Comment: You're right I had an unnecessary jQuery-ification there, thanks.

Comment: We should gather more ways to do this in a chain, 3 is not enough :D

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).nextAll().andSelf().remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `.nextAll()` and then just add `this` and then call `.remove()` on the combined set:

```
$(this).nextAll().add(this).remove();
```